# How to import data types from RIA Services to silverlight

Tags: wcf, web-services, silverlight, ria

I'm using a RIA service to transfer data to my silverlight application , i added a reference for this service to my silverlight application.

i have a method that return a custom class like this

```
public class ReturnData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// detects if there is an error or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool Error
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// If there is an error this contains the error
    /// </summary>
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Data
    /// </summary>
    public object Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

i use it to tell my application if error happened in the operation and deliver message in case of error or success the Data field of type object is used to contain the returned data it's sometimes string, int, ... or a custom object.

the problem is that when i use the service like this

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client s = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
s.GetDirectoriesCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.GetDirectoriesCompletedEventArgs>(s_GetDirectoriesCompleted);
s.GetDirectoriesAsync(null);
/*
in s_GetDirectoriesCompleted method i use e.Result to get ReturnData object but i has none of the members implemented in the service
*/
```

i can't access my implemented properties is there any thing required to accomplish this.

also when i return a custom object in ReturnData.Data how can i reference or use it in my application

Comment: I couldn't solve this in ria but i moved to asmx web service and added the following tag above the mehtod [XmlInclude(typeof(DirectoryFileInfo))]

Answer (score 0):

If I am right then you are talking about WCF-RIA services right? If yes then it's quite simple, you see, you just need to do 3 things:
1. Create a class in the .Web side as you have above.
2. Create a function in your DomainService (which I believe you might have added :) ) with return type of "ReturnData"
3. Next in the Client side of the application use invoke operation to call the function and get the value it returns.